# Как получить список файлов которые внутри виртуальных Shell папок с помощью C#?

Tags: c#

Например если создать папку с именем Applications.{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1} то при открытии проводником там видны файлы.

Нужно получить список файлов которые внутри виртуальной Shell папки

Подробнее о них здесь http://g-ek.com/clsid-guid-spisok-shell-v-windows-10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно работать с объектами оболочки, Shell32. Кажется, самый простой путь для этого — воспользоваться скриптуемым ActiveX-объектом `Shell`.

Это не так ужасно, как кажется. Для начала, вам нужно подключить необходимый COM-объект в ссылки:

[image: add shell activex]

После этого у вас появится пространство имён `Shell32`. Теперь можно написать вот такой код:

```
[STAThread] // <-- это для COM, без него работать не будет
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var shell = new Shell32.Shell();
    var folder = shell.NameSpace("shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}");
    var items = folder.Items();
    foreach (Shell32.FolderItem item in items)
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
```

Если у вас есть лишь полный путь к каталогу, можно указать и его:

```
    var folder = shell.NameSpace(@"Z:\Applications.{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}");
```

У меня, например, выдаёт следующее:

> Mozilla Firefox
>   ...
>   x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017
>   About Java
>   Mobility Center
>   ...
>   Управление компьютером
>   Монитор ресурсов
>   ...
>   Этот компьютер
>   Панель управления
>   Проводник
>   Проигрыватель Windows Media
>   ...
>   Будильники и часы
>   Калькулятор
>   Камера
>   Календарь
>   Почта
>   ...

---

**Обновление**

Того же эффекта можно добиться проще, подключив nuget-пакет [Windows API Code Pack - Shell](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAPICodePack-Shell/).

Ваш код будет выглядеть так:

```
var sf = (ShellFolder)ShellObject.FromParsingName(
                            "shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}");
// или просто var sf = (ShellFolder)KnownFolders.Programs;
foreach (var item in sf)
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
```